# Is there a way to find all tables that reference another table/column in DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

I have a relatively large DBeaver database and am trying to find all tables and possibly columns reference a specific table/column. I can't find anything on SO or anywhere else relating to this question. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I did not find such functionality in the interface, however this answer provides a helpful SQL https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137737

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Feature Support

Since DBeaver 7.0.0, this has been added as a `Major Feature` in Table objects
(it is major because it exists on any table expandable view).

Their release notes ([github](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/releases/tag/7.0.0) or [official page](https://dbeaver.com/release-notes/)) are not very detailed, unfortunately. However, I will provide an overview of the feature at it is really helpful.

### References - Feature Overview

Here is a brief overview of how it works:

1. From **Database Navigator** go to the table you want
2. Select the expand icon
3. Select the **References** option

> Any references to your table will be listed below. Note that, each table may have zero, one, or more references to your table.

4. If you just want to get the list of tables (with possible duplicates as mentioned before), you can select all the references, `right-click`, and from the context menu select `Copy Advanced Info`. This will copy to your clipboard the references in the following form: `[Schema].[OwnerTable].[ReferenceName]` from which you can isolate the table names.
5. Also, a more detailed view is available on double-click `References`

### References - Demonstration Example

As a demonstration, I will use one of the most popular sample databases, the `Chinook` database. It's always freely available on [github](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database)

Suppose that you need to know which tables are referencing the table `Track`.

#### From Navigator

[image: Dbeaver References Demonstration]

#### Or more detailed view with double click

[image: Dbeaver References Detailed Demonstration]

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in the interface through the UML view.

1. Open the table you want to find the related tables of
2. In the top menu click on ER Diagram (next to Properties and Data)

Answer (score 1):

Found this way out in `DBeaver`:-

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS;
```

Comment: I get this answer:
SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS)